# How to populate combobox with records in database

Tags: database, delphi

I am trying to populate my combobox with school names from my database. I have hard coded the procedure per combobox using this code:

```
procedure TfrmSportsDay.PopulateCmbOpponentASE;
var
  sLine: String;
begin
  cmbOpponentASE.Items.Clear;
  with DM_Sport do
  begin
    tblSchools.First;
    while not tblSchools.eof do
    begin
      sLine := tblSchools['SchoolName'];
      cmbOpponentASE.Items.Add(sLine);
      tblSchools.Next;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This fills the specific combobox by me manually entering the name, is there a way in which the combobox's name can be inputted in the Procedure and that I therefore have 1 procedure to populate comboboxes and don't have to write one for each?

e.g.

```
Private
Procedure PopulateCmb(sComboBoxName : String);

Procedure PopulateCmb(sComboBoxName : String);
var
  sLine: String;
begin
  {sComboBoxName}.Items.Clear;
  with DM_Sport do
  begin
    tblSchools.First;
    while not tblSchools.eof do
    begin
      sLine := tblSchools['SchoolName'];
      {sComboBoxName}.Items.Add(sLine);
      tblSchools.Next;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/

Comment: https://lp.embarcadero.com/Object-Pascal-Handbook-2021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing an argument withe the combobox name, just pass as argument the variable that is the combobox (In the code you showed it is cmbOpponentASE).

```
procedure PopulateCmb(Combo : TComboBox);
var
  sLine: String;
begin
  Combo.Items.Clear;
  with DM_Sport do
  begin
    tblSchools.First;
    while not tblSchools.eof do
    begin
      sLine := tblSchools['SchoolName'];
      Combo.Items.Add(sLine);
      tblSchools.Next;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And call it like this:

```
PopulateCmb(cmbOpponentASE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using kbmMW SmartBinding, it is as easy as this:

```
Binding.Bind(DM_Sport.tblSchools,'SchoolName',cmbOpponentASE,'Items');
```

And if you want the dataset current record to reflect which item you have selected in the combobox then also add:

```
Binding.Bind(DM_Sport.tblSchools,'@',cmbOpponentASE,'@',[mwboTwoWay]);
```

kbmMW is a toolbox that fully supports Delphi and all platforms.
Read more at http://components4developers.blog
Search for SmartBind and you will find 6 blog posts showing how easy it is to use it.